# Not able to add a data attribute to element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a data attribute to the SaveSection anchor, but it isn't working. In the jQuery docs, it shows being able to add a data attribute as I am doing, but its not happening

```js
$('#SaveSection').data("admin-section", "vendorcatalogs");
```

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="SaveSection"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp; Save</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not happening?

Comment: @Taplar, when i inspect the element, there is no data attribute

Comment: jQuery stores data in in memory cache, not on the element itself

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine. Note that `data()` stores values in an object which jQuery holds in memory, it does not update the DOM. So long as you use `data()` as both getter *and* setter, the logic works fine:

```js
var $saveSection = $('#SaveSection').data("admin-section", "vendorcatalogs");
console.log($saveSection.data('admin-section'));
```

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="SaveSection">
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp; Save
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you still require the `data` attribute to appear in the DOM, then use `attr()` instead of `data()`, but note this will be slower:

```js
var $saveSection = $('#SaveSection').attr("data-admin-section", "vendorcatalogs");
console.log($saveSection.attr('data-admin-section'));
```

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="SaveSection">
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp; Save
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It should be noted that there is another reason for this, other than performance.  `data()` allows for the storage of things other than strings, where as attributes on the object can only be strings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, will mark as answer once I am able to

Comment: No problem, glad to help